# wordpress Data Table Lazy Loading concept

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, datatables

I am working on a WordPress project. In which I applied the DataTable in front-end Theme page. My page DataTable is working fine but it is having many for ... loops. So, it decreases the page speed. I want to apply the lazy loading concept of dataTable and my dataTable content is having the HTML content also.

I have googled it and found this example. So can anyone help me for "How to use this solution with my data are coming from AJAx Request?"

**example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    for ( var i=0 ; i<50000 ; i++ ) {
        data.push( [ i, i, i, i, i ] );
    }

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data:           data,
        deferRender:    true,
        scrollY:        200,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller:       true
    } );
} );
```

DataTable example - [Client-side data source (50,000 rows)](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html)

I am having the following format for my DataTable,

```
foreach($wp_user_search as $user_id)
......
$return = "<tr class=\"$bclass\" data-id='" . $user_id . "' >";
$return .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="filterEmails[]" class="filterEmails" value="' . $user_email . '"></td>';
$return .= '<td class="th_name"><span class="filter_name" data-popup-open="popup-user-tabs" data-userid="' . $user_id . '">' . $user_name . '</span><form method="get" action="aa" style="float: right"><input type="hidden" name="userid" value="' . $user_id . '"/><button type="submit">Details</button></form></td>';
$return .= '<td class="th_title">' . $user_meta['user_title'][0] . '</td>';
$return .= '<td class="th_email">' . $user_email . '</td>';
....
}
```

**Required:** Want to apply DataTable filter's to my WordPress AJAX data.

Thanks in advance.